# HDD shows up in Partition Wizard, but not in BIOS or in Windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, sata

I have a new SATA HDD for my ASUS G73JH Laptop. This is simply a bigger HDD(2TB) than the one before  and it's new and unsused. Windows 7 Ultimate runs on a second HDD (SSD). The new SATA HDD is not recognized in BIOS and also not in Windows Partition Manager.

But when I boot with the tool Partition Wizard, then I can explore the new disk, format it, test it, whatever.
This HDD is a SATAIII NTFS formatted MBR disk (not GPT). I also rebuilt the boot record already, updated my BIOS and of course all my drivers in Windows 7.

My system info:

- Asus G73JH Laptop
- 128GB Samsung SSD
- 2TB Samsung Spinpoint M9T SATA III HDD (here's the problem)
- 500GB Seagate SATA (that is the one I had before the new Samsung HDD)

Any idea on how I can make the new HDD usable in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I have a G73JW-XA1 and was able to get the drive to work as my windows drive but also wanted to use it as you have described. I got another one for the second bay and it just simply does not want to show up in the current bios or Windows, but will show up when I use a Linux based partition manager just fine.

Frustrating that I know it can be seen by the computer, but not used.

You may be able to use it in the first bay and still boot from the second bay if you reinstall Windows to your SSD in the second bay.